# Split a string in to pieces based on its length in 'pixels'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I split a php string by its length in pixels when its echoed in a label? I know that its possible to split a string based on its length by number of characters.

```
<?php
   $strng = str_split($strng, 20);
?>
```

By using the above code I am just able to split the string regard less of the length it occupies on the screen after certain length. But is there any way to split the string based on the length it occupies in pixels when it is echoed in the tags like below..

```
   <label id='label1'><?php echo $strng;?></label>
```

This question may sound crazy, but i just want to know is there any possible way to do it.. By just not using PHP

Comment: PHP can't tell how many pixels it will use in the browser.

Comment: Yes, but is just want to know is there any different way to do it.. @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP runs on the server and **does not know anything from the frontend**. So PHP don't know the CSS or HTML and because of that you can't know how many pixels long the String will be.

What you may do is to define manually how long (in pixels) the diffrent digits are and then calculate it. But that's not a good way at all:

```
$digits = [
    "a" => 10,
    "b" => 12,
    // ..
    "H" => 15,
    "l" => 7,
    "o" => 9
];
$str = "Hallo";
$total = 0;
for ($x=0;$x<strlen($str);$x++) {
    $d = $str[$x];
    $total += $digits[$d];
}
echo $total;
```

To calculate thins in the frontend you better use JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript.
The simplest way would be to put it in an inline component which is in a component scrollable on x axis - in case the text length is wider than the parent (browser window).
Then you just measure the width of the inline component. (using jQuery $("#myComponent").width() )

For instance, using jquery:

```
var e = $("#myElement");
while(e.width()>max_pixels){
    e.html(e.html().substring(0,e.html().length-1));
}
```